# How to cache all Discord.JS messages / How to get a message position

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Discord.JS has this property of getting all [messages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages) from a text channel.

In the channel where I eval the code, I have (let's say) 100 messages. When I run the command & to shorten console, I do `message.channel.messages.forEach(m => console.log(m.content)}` content is a string, I get only 3 contents only. I'm assuming this happens due to caching issues or something related, but How do I get all 100/100 messages instead of 3/100 messages?

To get into even more at what I'm trying to get at, I'm trying to get a message's position in a channel since no property exists for a message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Channel#fetchMessages()`.

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.get('channel_id');
channel.messages.size; // 3
channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 90 }).then((fetchedChannel) => {
    console.log(fetchedChannel.messages.size); // 90
});
```

Here you have the full documentation of the function: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages

Comment: for the .then() statement, that shows an individual message object, not the channel, also something else that I want to take into consideration is to grab every message in the channel.